# How to detect when a radio button in a DataGrid is selected?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid on my webapge that looks like this:

```
<asp:datagrid id="dgCodes" runat="server" bodyHeight="300px" CssClass="tblScroll" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="clsGridHeaderText"
            HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Select
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <INPUT type="radio" name="chkSelect"  TabIndex="-1" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code") %>' onclick="mfpSetCode(this);"  <%# mfpDisable(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code")) %>>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

So there's 1 radio button column titled "Select", and then a few columns get added once the data is bound to the DataGrind.

When the user selects a radio button in this DataGrid, it's supposed to populate 2 child DataGrids, using a unique value in one of the bound columns.

I was able to set a SelectedIndexChanged event for the grid, hoping that'd catch the selection of the radio button column and then I could get the data that way, but it does not.

How can I get some data when a RB is selected like this?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `<asp:RadioButton>` instead. This will give you the `OnCheckChanged` event.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbSelect" runat="server"
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code") %>'
    OnCheckChanged="rbSelect_CheckChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Then handle the event in your code behind.

```
Protected Sub rbSelect_CheckChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
{

}
```

Comment: That event does not seem to fire when selecting rows in the grid during run time. Am I missing something?

Comment: It shouldn't fire when you select the row. It should fire when you click the RadioButton on the row.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Wasn't getting caught. Tried adding the 'Handles rbSelect.CheckedChanged' after the event stub, tried manually attaching the handler in the PageLoad. Either way, could never trigger a breakpoint in the event when selecting the radio buttons. I *think* it might be the PostBack "interrupting" things, as the Page_Load gets fired each time I was selecting something.

Comment: That is possible. Make sure you aren't binding your DataGrid on every single PostBack.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the case- the grids do get re-bound on PostBack. To be honest I'm not 100% sure why, something to do with the pagination of the grids I believe. New job and I'm not completely familiar with the codebase / logic yet :(

Comment: Well if it's not needed, no reason you can't take it out. In order to get pagination working though, you must rebind. __But__, you can also do that in pagination specific methods rather than `Page_Load` so that it doesn't negatively affect the rest of your app.